# Полсе установки ffmpeg перестала работать автовыдача ролей и приветственное сообщение

Tags: python, discord

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
    await ctx.message.delete()

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    await ctx.message.delete()

@client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['p', 'pla'])
async def play(ctx, url: str):

    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
            print("Removed old song file")
    except PermissionError:
        print("Trying to delete song file, but it's being played")
        await ctx.send("ERROR: Music playing")
        return

    await ctx.send("Getting everything ready now")

    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        print("Downloading audio now\n")
        ydl.download([url])

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            name = file
            print(f"Renamed File: {file}\n")
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: print("Song done!"))
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.07

    nname = name.rsplit("-", 2)
    await ctx.send(f"Playing: {nname[0]}")
    print("playing\n")



# Send welcome message to channel



#async def on_member_join(member):
    #channel = client.get_channel (756134695833567364)
    #role = discord.utils.get (member.guild.add_roles, id = 759477140852047924)
    #await member.add_roles ( role )
    #await channel.send(emb = discord.Embed(description = f'Привет, **{member.name}** пропиши /help, чтобы узнать список команд'))
@client.command (pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True)
async def ban (ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    channel1 = client.get_channel (758393130755162123)
    await ctx.channel.purge (limit =1) #тут есть ошибка. Если что поменяй 1 на бесконечность
    await member.ban( reason = reason)
    await channel1.send(f'Данный пользователь нарушил правила сервера и был забанен{member.mention }')
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channelsadg = client.get_channel(756134695833567364) # Where ID is your welcome channel's ID
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name = 'Beginner' )
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await channelsadg.send(f'Привет, {member}! Ты попал в канал {member.guild.name}. Чтобы узнать мои команды пропипши /help') 
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channelsadz = client.get_channel(756134695833567364)
    await channelsadz.send(f"{member} {random.choice(bah)}")
```

До этого всё было нормально. После установки библиотеки перестала работать функция.